# beanutils is not ignoring null in Date field

Tags: java, date, apache-commons-beanutils

[How to set date type values using Apache Commons BeanUtils,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912437/how-to-set-date-type-values-using-apache-commons-beanutils)

I had the same problem as in the above question. When I set date field using beanutils it throws **DateConverter does not support default String to 'Date' conversion.**

I used the same fix given in the above thread.

```
DateConverter converter = new DateConverter();
converter.setPattern("dd/mm/yyyy");
ConvertUtils.register(converter, Date.class);
BeanUtils.setProperty(obj, "date", "07/04/2014");
```

Now it works but whenever null value comes, it throws
**.ConversionException: No value specified for 'Date'**

So, I searched google and added the line:

```
BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getConvertUtils().register(false, false, 0);
```

Now date conversion itself is not happening. It is ignoring all Dates. Is it possible to ignore null and convert date?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
java.util.Date defaultValue = null;//or not null value if it comes null than replace defaultValue
DateConverter converter = new DateConverter(defaultValue);
```